# how to compare a BigDecimal number to see if it is a whole number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using a BigDecimal to represent a price and want to have numbers that are equal to whole number not have the fractional part and numbers with a non-zero fractional part show two digits. Such as:

```
value    outputs
12.0     12
12.25    12.25
12.87    12.87
```

I have but it's always showing as two digits:

```
if !price.price.nil? && price.price.frac=='0.0' # this comparison is not working correctly
  s=helpers.number_to_currency(price.price, precision: 0, format: "%n")
else
  s=helpers.number_to_currency(price.price, precision: 2, format: "%n")
end
```

How would I compare a BigDecimal to see if it would be a whole number?

thx

Answer (score 1):

`.frac` doesn't produce a String, it produces a BigDecimal. You can try the following:

`if !price.price.nil? && price.price.frac==0`

That should be the comparison you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing for the fraction, use a NumberFormat object:

```
public static String formatNicely(BigDecimal bd) {
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    formatter.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    return formatter.format(bd);
}
```